# JPA Criteria API filter subentities

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpa-criteria

The code example:

```
    @Entity
    public class Event {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="event")
    private List<Actions> actions;

    }


    @Entity
    public class Action {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Date date;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "event_id")
    private Event event;

    }

    public class EventSpecification {

    public static Specification<Event> findByCriteria(EventSearchCriteria criteria) {

        return (root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) -> {
            List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

            criteria.getDate().ifPresent(date -> {
                Join<Event, Action> join = root.join(Event_.actions);
                predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(join.get(Action_.date), criteria.getDate().get()));
            });

            return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
        };
    }
    }
...

eventRepository.findAll(EventSpecification.findByCriteria(searchCriteria))
```

In my database I have the next:

```
Event Table
id, name
1, 'event_1'
2, 'event_2'

Action Table
id, name, date, event_id
1, 'action_event_1_1', '01-01-2018', 1
2, 'action_event_1_2', '01-01-2018', 1
3, 'action_event_1_3', '01-02-2018', 1

4, 'action_event_2_1', '01-03-2018', 2
```

Using my Specification code with data='01-01-2018', as a result I get a list of identical Event objects and the list's size is count of joined objects, that fulfill the claus Action.date = criteria.date:

```
[{id=1, name=event_1, actions=[all 3 actions]},
{id=1, name=event_1, actions=[all 3 actions]}]
```

I need to get the next result:

```
{id=1, name=event_1, actions=[only two actions with date '01-01-2018']}
```

I tried to add

```
criteriaQuery.groupBy(root.get(Event.id));
```

It fixes resulted list size -

```
{id=1, name=event_1, actions=[all 3 actions]}
```

but I still get all 3 actions of event 1.

**The question is:**

Is it possible to get only Events, that contain Actions with a required date and so that each Event contains only a list with Actions with the requested date?

Answer (score 1):

I found the next solution:

```
public static Specification<Event> findByCriteria(EventSearchCriteriacriteria) {

        return (root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) -> {
            List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

            criteria.getDate().ifPresent(date -> {
                criteriaQuery.distinct(true);
                Join<Event, Action> join = (Join<Event, Action>)root.fetch(Event_.actions);
                predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(join.get(Action_.date), criteria.getDate().get()));
            });

            return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
        };
    }
```

Probably `Join<Event, Action> join = (Join<Event, Action>)root.fetch(Event_.actions);` isn't the best solution, because my IDE warns me regarding the casting, but this is the only working solution I found.

By the way, it works perfect if not to use Criteria API:

```
@EntityGraph(value = "Event.actions", type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.LOAD)
@Query("select distinct e from Event e join e.actions a where a.date = (:date)")
List<Event> findAllWithActionsByDate(@Param("date") Date date);
```

But the avoiding of Criteria API is unfit in my case.

Comment: Why don't you use directly `Join<Event, Action> join = root.join(Event_.actions)` ? No need to cast

Comment: The field actions has lazy initialization. Only fetch let's me get what I need in "single" db query - "...each Event contains only a list with Actions with the requested date". Using join instead, I get only Events objects, but not Actions with Action.date=date.

Comment: Ah ok. Have you tried using `join` instead of `fetch` and applying the `EntityGraph` hint as shown in Oracle's [Java EE Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-entitygraphs003.htm)?

Comment: No, I haven't, but I think it should work. I didn't do it because it is harder to do than fetch approach in my case, I show here only small part of my filter... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this JPQL query:

```
select e from Events e join Actions a with a.date=:date
group by e
```

Comment: I can, but is it possible to do, using specification? I'm trying to implement a search filter, so it's important to do it in this way.