# JPA 2 criteria query, where on property list class

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

I'd like to achieve the query below using criteria typed query:

```
SELECT
    a.*
FROM
    table_a a
    INNER JOIN table_b b ON a.id= b.id
WHERE
    b.url = 'value.org';
```

Criteria query:

```
    final CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    final CriteriaQuery<A> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(A.class);
    final Root<A> root = criteriaQuery.from(A.class);
    root.fetch(A.domains); // domains is a List<B>
    criteriaQuery
            .select(root);
```

Entity A:

```
  @OneToMany
  List<B> domains;
```

Entity B:

```
  @Column(name="URL")
  String url;
```

My issue is how to reproduce where, I've tried something like:

```
 .where(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(A.domains).. ??))
```

but I don't know how to continue, because proposal clause are as(), in(..), etc..

Any hints?

Comment: Please go through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29145958/jpa-criteria-builder-onetomany-restrictions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, You don't need to fetch as you only want to get a.
Second, You are almost good only important missing part is `join`.
Here is code that should work for You:

```
public A loadAForValueOrg() {
    CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<A> query = builder.createQuery(A.class);
    Root<A> a = query.from(A.class);
    Join<A, B> b = a.join("domains");
    query.select(A);
    query.where(builder.equal(b.get("url"), "'value.org'"));
    TypedQuery<A> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(query);
    typedQuery.setMaxResults(1);
    List<A> result = typedQuery.getResultList();
    return result.isEmpty() ? null : result.get(0);
}
```

Few considerations:

- `setMaxResults` is not need, only good practice for performance
- If no result we return `null` so it is good candidate for Java 8 `Optional`
- Also I recommended use [metamodel](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/topical/html/metamodelgen/MetamodelGenerator.html) to not operate on strings(its are error-prone)

Comment: about Java8 Optional, with JPA 2.2 you can also use .getResultStream().
So the code would be entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery)
                .getResultStream()
                .findAny()
                .orElse(null);